# fastest way to install Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a fast way to install Joomla that will create the database and the admin login and install the relevant files from one script?

Mat

Comment: What's wrong with the current installation process? It only takes about 30 seconds. There are 1-click-install feature that some hosting providers provide you.

Comment: +1 @Lodder. The Joomla installer does exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way Joomla can create a database on your hosting account during installation, except on localhost (Wampserver, Xampp etc.) where you usually can add the database on the fly using the 'root' user. You will have to create the database manually and take note of the access details.

However, if you want to save a couple of seconds downloading and uploading the Joomla installation file, you can use the [Pro version of Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) (subscription based). This script has a time-saving feature that lets you download any web accessible file directly to your server, by simply inserting the URL. It even has buttons to instantly download the latest version of Joomla (or WordPress).

[image: Akeeba Kickstart]

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I'm not in any way affiliated with or endorsed by Akeeba Ltd.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the installer included with your hosting control panel, then no, there isn't a "one size fits all" script that creates the database and installs Joomla for you.

Installing Joomla is usually a 2 step process:

1. create a database, create a database user and assign permissions for the database user to the database
2. upload the Joomla install file to the server, expand the file and run the install script

The reason it can't be any simpler is because the database creation process varies depending on the hosting environment e.g. cPanel compared to Plesk.

Joomla is not unique in this respect and it is a similar story for other PHP/MySQL content management systems such as WordPress etc.

Once you have done this a few times, a Joomla install should only take a few minutes.